# can HornetQ server(eap 6) communicate to jms-clients in eap 5?

Tags: jms, hornetq, bridge, jboss-eap-6

I have a requirement for HornetQ server(jboss eap 6) communicate to jms-clients in jboss eap 5? If so how please help me on this.

And also i created a jms bridge and works fine but the problem is the hornetq server duplicates messages in jms server(JBoss EAP5).

But my intension here is jms clients(eap 5) should connect to hornetq on eap 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an developement effort to make it compatible. So far our rule of thumb was always server-version > client... the opposite not being tested...

this may change in a near future.. but so far that's been the rule.

This is being done per: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-1242

Comment: I believe I have answered to have answered your question... I would appreciate accepting it

Comment: thanks for your answer..

is there a way i can try configuring it with existing eap(5.1 & 6.2) version.. Just i would like to give a try any inputs greatly appreciated thanks..

Comment: You can EAP 5 clients sending and consuming messages on EAP 6.2 without any problems.